# while importing XML file in Wordpress nothing happens

Tags: xml, wordpress, import

I'm trying to inherit the demo contents of a theme to my website and what i'm trying to do is that i've a xml file and i'm trying to import it via Wordpress dashboard -> Tools -> import -> xml file but after 100 % it just brings me a blank screen and nothing happens to it.
How to fix it